# Can LSTM networks predict the output for another similar sequential data?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

1. Suppose I train my LSTM on one sequence of data and validate it by predicting data for the next few steps.
2. If the model is working well can this model be saved?
3. And the saved model be used to predict the output for a similar sequential of data but the input parameter values are modified a bit.

OR **LSTMs can just predict the next few steps of the same sequence of data ???**

[Data Table for reference Please Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYbja.png)

Suppose I have a process data with the input and output features available and this is a sequential data and suppose my LSTM is learning from the 3 steps of data to predict the next step.

Now this LSTM will only predict the future data for this process or can it predict the output values for a new set of input parameters even at the beginning of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, latter one is definitely supported - it can predict the output values for the unseen data even for the initial steps.

Regarding the prior option - "*Now this LSTM will only predict the future data for this process*", I must say that there seems to be something dubious:

> Let's take an problem statement to understand the concept in detail:
>
> > **Problem Statement**: Predict next word after typing each word keeping the context length a little longer than what does RNN support [also data size = 10 million sentences]

> Now, are you saying that ideally we should train the model for 10 million sentences, but only for first 4-5 words and then validate whether model is working fine or not based on the left out words for each sentence in the training data ?

If the above is the case, I would suggest: (**This is overlapping with your latter option**)

> Divide the data into training, validate and test data and train the model on complete sentences from training data and then validate it by giving the input from validation data and calculate accuracy for every predicted word.